# Photo naming error (QField)

Tags: qfield, photos

Follow the instructions at https://qfield.org/docs/prepare/picture_path.html?highlight=photo

I write the following route to "Photo naming":

```
'DCIM / INV / INV_' || (now () || '.jpg'
```

But it only generates a DCIM folder with all the photos and named JPEG ... as if it wasn't set up:

```
DCIM / JPEG_20210924091021590.jpg
```

Where is the error? Do I need to do something else?

Comment: You have an open bracket `(now ()`

Answer (score 3):

There is an superfluous parenthesis before now(), i.e. you have '(now ()' The additional white spaces are also confusing. Try

```
'DCIM/INV/INV_'||now()||'.jpg'
```

or if you want to format your date so it is more readable, something like

```
'DCIM/INV/INV_'||format_date(Now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss')||'.jpg'
```